# printf command within Bash throwing error

Tags: bash, shell, awk, printf

I am using the following command in  bash to subtract 2 numbers and print the result. Using `bc` tool as well

```
printf '\n"runtime": %s' "$(($a - $b) | bc -l)"
```

But getting an error

`1517359690.775414500: command not found`

How should i rewrite my `printf` command?

Comment: Please, **please** don't generate JSON with syntax-unaware tools. `jq` can not only do the math internally, it can generate output that's guaranteed to be properly escaped and otherwise well-formed.

Comment: BTW -- you're tagged for both `sh` and `bash`. They're different languages -- which one are you targeting?

Comment: I am not able to understand your comment...will be helpful if you can give some example

Comment: I am using `bash`

Comment: I believe my answer should now adequately demonstrate why `jq` is more capable than `printf` for purposes of generating JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your shell is bash, then this could be:

```
printf '\n"runtime": %s' "$(bc -l <<<"($a - $b)")"
```

If instead your shell is sh, then this could be:

```
printf '\n"runtime": %s' "$(echo "($a - $b)" | bc -l)"
```

Note that we're invoking a separate command -- `echo` -- whose output is piped into `bc`, rather than trying to run the numbers as a command themselves.

---

**However, you shouldn't be using `printf` to create JSON documents in the first place.**

Instead, use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
start=5.5; stop=6.10
other_value='this is an example string
it crosses multiple lines, and has "literal quotes" within it'
jq -nc \
   --argjson start "$start" \
   --argjson stop "$stop" \
   --arg other_value "$other_value" \
  '{"runtime": ($stop - $start), "other key": $other_value}'
```

You'll note that the string here is correctly escaped to be included in JSON: `"` is changed to `\"`, the literal newline is changed to `\n`, and so forth.

Comment: Plus one for finding the immediate need `jq` here. :)